# Ajax firing success event but not getting to the web method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to call a server side function. for some reason, the success is firing but it doesn't get to the function
here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Server.aspx/sendEmail",
        data: { name: "foo", company: "bar", country: "foo", email: "bar", msg: "bla" },
        async: false,

        success: function (data) {
            var a = 3;
        },
        error: function (a, b) {
            alert("error");
            var a = 43;

        }
    });
});
```

here is the c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string sendEmail(string name, string company, string country, string email, string msg)
{
    //somecode here
}
```

the data message(for some reason it is breaking)

> ```
> <form method="post" action="./sendEmail?%7b%22name%22%3a%22foo%22%2c%22company%22%3a%22bar%22%2c%22country%22%3a%22foo%22%2c%22email%22%3a%22bar%22%2c%22msg%22%3a%22bla%22%7d" id="form1">
> ```

```
<div>

</div>
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="368A1591" />
```

Comment: Doesn't get to _which_ function...? The ajax success firing does not necessarily mean your C# actually sent an email, just that ajax got a valid response from the server.

Comment: It doesn't get to the C# web method.(sendEmail)

Comment: AJAX calls use GET by default, but you need to POST.  Add `type: "post"` to the options.  Also, which version of .Net are you using?  I had a hell of a time getting web methods to work with .Net 2.0 aspx files.

Comment: Adding type: "post" didn't help and I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: What's in `data` in the success function?

Comment: it keeps breaking the message is in the text editor here. is there any way i can send it to ypu privatly?

Comment: if you send it to someone privately then no-one else can try to help you, which is against the spirit of the site and also gives you less chance of an answer. Can you paste your info into the comments, if not the question?

Comment: it is too long unfortunately. I can post it in a few comment but I know this site can be a bit senstive about posting a few things in a row

Comment: If it's too long then likely not all of it is relevant - try and extract the most useful parts of the message. Is it an error message or just some data? If it's just data, then you maybe don't need to paste it, you just need to tell us if that's the data you actually expected to be returned. You haven't shown any code inside the email function which indicates what the expected output should be.

Comment: P.S. Why are you using `async:false`? It's deprecated in some browsers, so you can expect it to stop working in future. Also, it's almost never necessary in reality, and it causes horrible user experience - it locks the whole browser, so if the request takes longer than expected, the user may assume the browser has crashed and kill it.

Comment: i have added it to the question. i really dont think it is relvant. I know when there is something important in it, hope you will find and no reason for the async false it was just for checking

Comment: that's bizarre. It's returning some form HTML containing your values in the querystring? That doesn't make any sense at all. Are you sure it's not posting the whole page back?

Comment: No. How can I make sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the following points into account when you are calling an ASP.NET AJAX page methods:

- To use [ASP.NET AJAX page methods](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Using-jQuery-to-directly-dc96f7ab), you need to make a POST request. This is to prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))
- Ensure that the `contentType` is set to `application/json`.
- Use `JSON.stringify` to convert the JavaScript object into JSON text.

Your JS code could be something similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = { name: "foo", company: "bar", country: "foo", email: "bar", msg: "bla" };
    $.ajax({
        url: "Server.aspx/sendEmail",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            //Do something 
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status
                + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText
                + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

If it still doesn't work, check the `statusText` for the error.

Comment: it telling me this:    

An attempt was made to call the method \u0027sendEmail\u0027 using a POST request, which is not allowed

Comment: have you added any attributes to the `sendEmail` function?

Comment: Yes i did while I was Checking. It is working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice! Glad to help.